# Can we say "I am preparing food for you"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [Prepare](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prepare?q=prepare): to make something or somebody ready to be used or to do
> something
>
> For example, I am preparing a room for you

I have just cooked potatoes and meat and my children can eat them together.

Is it correct for me to say "**Honey, wait a second, I am preparing food for you**" when I mean I am putting the potatoes and meat on a plate and give them to my children?

Comment: **Preparing food** refers to the whole process of cooking, not just 'dishing up' the food.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* say it, but you wouldn't sound like a native speaker, because we wouldn't say that.

'Preparation' of food would refer to the entire process of making food. It might include serving, as "food preparation" is often used as a term for work in the food service industry. People cooking at home might say "I'm preparing dinner" to mean cooking, but are more likely to say they are *cooking*, or *making* dinner (in American English I believe they also commonly say 'fixing' dinner).

For the process of putting food on a plate, the most common expressions would be:

- I'm *serving* your food
- I'm *dishing up* your food (particularly in BrEng)
- I'm *plating* the food (more likely in a food industry setting)

Comment: Ok, now your friend comes to your house and wants to stay over night there. You have a small room which is a bit messy but not too messy. It will take you 5 minutes to tidy the room. Do you say "Let me prepare the room for you"? Is that a different context?

Comment: "I'm preparing a plate for you" is a common expression in American conversation for the situation the OP describes.